# Unexpected reset of read_only_allow_delete

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

In some of my indices, I'm doing `"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": true` by using the `PUT /index/_settings` API call. But after around 10 seconds, the setting disappears and the index is writable again.

I'm wondering if this can be a bug in ES, as in version 6.8 a change was made to reset this setting automatically when a node whose disk had gone over the flooding stage, was again below the normal thresholds.

I'm experiencing that odd behaviour in ES 7.9. What I expected is that, if ES changed the setting to `true` because of the watermarks, then it could reset it to `false` later. But if an operator changes the setting to `true` manually, then ES was going to respect that setting.

[These are the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/modules-cluster.html#disk-based-shard-allocation) where I read about that behaviour:

> Controls the flood stage watermark, which defaults to 95%. Elasticsearch enforces a read-only index block ( `index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete` ) on every index that has one or more shards allocated on the node, and that has at least one disk exceeding the flood stage. This setting is a last resort to prevent nodes from running out of disk space. **The index block is automatically released when the disk utilization falls below the high watermark.**

Cross-posted [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/unexpected-reset-of-read-only-allow-delete/248885).

Comment: Did you find the solution to update this setting?

Comment: Yes, I had to start using index.blocks.read_only instead, as that one is not being reset automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `index.blocks.read_only` instead, as this one is not updated by ElasticSearch automatically.